# Evaluate the integral by type1 or type 2

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\log(x)}(x-1)\sqrt{1+e^y}\,dy\,dx$.
I have tried integration by substitution but can't connect to type 1 or type 2.
Any help.

Comment: Is the order of integration $dxdy$ or $dydx$?

Comment: @john it's dydx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of integration to obtain

$$\begin{align}
I&\equiv\int_0^1\int_0^{\log x}(x-1)\sqrt{1+e^y}dydx\\\\&=-\int_{-\infty}^0\int_0^{e^y}(x-1)\sqrt{1+e^y}dxdy\\\\&=-\int_{-\infty}^0\left(\frac12 e^{2y}-e^y\right)\sqrt{1+e^y}dxdy
\end{align}$$

Then, letting $y\to \log y$, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=-\int_0^1\left(\frac12 y-1\right)\sqrt{1+y}dy\\\\
&=-\int_1^2\left(\frac12 y-\frac32\right)y^{1/2}dy\\\\
&=\frac25\left(3\sqrt{2}-2\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice answer! I was sort of thinking along the same lines.

Comment: Thanks @John!  I'm at home and recovering from surgery last week and you just made my day!

Comment: Get well soon Dr. MV! Enjoy the weekend.

Comment: @John  Thanks.  And enjoy yours too.

Comment: A bit behind on the limits 0 to 1-z

Comment: I'm not sure as to the comment, but when changing the variable $y$ to $\log y$, we need to transform the limits of integration accordingly.  So, when $y$ was $-\infty$, $\log y=0$.  When $y$ was $0$, $\log y=1$.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea of what you mean by type-1 or type-2, but in any case:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\log x}(x-1)\sqrt{1+e^{y}}\,dy\,dx &=& \int_{0}^{1}\int_{1}^{x}(x-1)\sqrt{1+z}\,\frac{dz}{z}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}(1-x)\frac{\sqrt{2-z}}{1-z}\,dz\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-z}(1-x)\frac{\sqrt{2-z}}{1-z}\,dx\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-z^2}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2-z}}{1-z}\,dz\end{eqnarray*}$$
so:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}(1+z)\sqrt{2-z}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}(3-z)\sqrt{z}\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{2}{5}\left(3\sqrt{2}-2\right)}.$$

Comment: More about type 1 and type 2 regions (Fubini's theorem)-http://users.math.msu.edu/users/gnagy/teaching/11-fall/mth234/L22-234.pdf.

Comment: @John: oh, ok, so a type-1 region is a normal region with respect to the $x$-coordinate and a type-2 region is a normal region with respect to the $y$-coordinate. Since this problem boils down to an integration problem over the triangle $[0,1]^2\cap\{x+y\leq 1\}$, we have a region that is both type-1 and type-2.

Comment: A little different from mine.  Lots of ways to skin a cat.  Enjoy the weekend.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, precisely!

Comment: A bit behind on the limits 0 to 1-z

Comment: I have observed that y=log(y) and later z=1-z or
 how to move from step 1 to step 2 and how did you arrive at (sqrt(2-z))/(1-z)